# Link between the coefficient of $p$-form written in $p$-form basis, and in covector basis

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to check something with you because it is not totally clear in my book.

Imagine I have a p-form $\alpha$.

I know that I can write it on the p-form basis, ie :

$$ \alpha = \sum_{i_1<...<i_p} a_{i_1...i_p} dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p}$$

I could also define it like this :

$$ \alpha = \sum_{i_1 ... i_p} b_{i_1...i_p} dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p}$$

And if I write it on the basis of tensor p-covariant :

$$ \alpha = \sum_{i_1...i_p} \alpha_{i_1,...,.i_p} dx^{i_1} \otimes ... \otimes dx^{i_p}$$

With $\alpha_{i_1,...,.i_p}$ skew symmetric.

Now my goal is to determine the relationship between all thoose coefficients.

First, we have :

$$a_{i_1...i_p}=\sum_{\sigma} \epsilon(\sigma) b_{i_{\sigma(1)}...i_{\sigma(p)}}$$

Indeed, we juste used the antisymmetric property of $dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p}$

Now, I want to find the relationship with the coefficient of the basis of covariant tensors.

By definition, I have :

$$\alpha_{i_1,...,.i_p}=\alpha(\partial_{i_1},...,.\partial_{i_p})$$

Thus :

$$\alpha_{i_1,...,.i_p}=\alpha(\partial_{i_1},...,.\partial_{i_p})=\sum_{q_1 ... q_p} b_{q_1...q_p} dx^{q_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{q_p}(\partial_{i_1},...,.\partial_{i_p})$$

I know that (I will show if needed how I get to this result but it is juste using the definition of wedges and doing few manipulations)

$$ dx^{q_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{q_p}(\partial_{i_1},...,.\partial_{i_p}) = \delta^{q_1...q_p}_{i_1...i_p}$$

Where $\delta^{q_1...q_p}_{i_1...i_p}$ is a symbol that is +1 if $q_1...q_p$ is an even permutation of $i_1...i_p$, -1 if it is an odd one and 0 if it is not a permutation of the $i_1...i_p$.

And finally :

$$\alpha_{i_1,...,.i_p}=\sum_{q_1 ... q_p} \delta^{q_1...q_p}_{i_1...i_p} b_{q_1...q_p} = \sum_{\sigma} \epsilon(\sigma) b_{i_{\sigma(1)}...i_{\sigma(p)}}$$

So we have for $i_1 < .. < i_p $:

$$\alpha_{i_1,...,.i_p}=a_{i_1,...,.i_p}$$

In conclusion, we have 2+1 equations :

$$\forall i_1 < .. < i_p  : ~ a_{i_1...i_p}=\sum_{\sigma} \epsilon(\sigma) b_{i_{\sigma(1)}...i_{\sigma(p)}}$$

$$\forall (i_1,..., i_p)  : ~\alpha_{i_1...i_p}=\sum_{\sigma} \epsilon(\sigma) b_{i_{\sigma(1)}...i_{\sigma(p)}}$$

and thus

$$\forall i_1 < .. < i_p  : ~ a_{i_1...i_p}=\alpha_{i_1...i_p}$$

And we can deduce the other values of $\alpha_{i_1...i_p}$ by using its property of skew symmetry.

My question is :

**Do you agree with the results ?** In fact I am working with a differential geomtry book but they don't pass too much time on the relation between the p-form basis and the covariant tensor basis but I found this important to be able to do calculations. It is too important for continuing without a verification of if at least the results are true.

And if you have seen a mistake in the proof even if the results are true I would like to know it also.

And also : **is there a simple formula to compute $\alpha(v^1,...v^p)$**. Indeed I have all the ingredients to compute it for simple examples using $\forall i_1 < .. < i_p  : ~ a_{i_1...i_p}=\alpha_{i_1...i_p}$ but the results doesn't look to be very simple. Is there a generalised "easy" formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your notation. When you write $\alpha_{i_1\dots i_p} = a_{i_1\dots i_p}$, you must be assuming $i_1<i_2<\dots<i_p$. What if that isn't true?

You certainly need $\alpha$ to be skew-symmetric to start with, so $a_{i_1\dots i_p} = 0$ unless the $i_j$ are all distinct and $a_{\sigma(i_1)\dots \sigma(i_p)} = \text{sgn}(\sigma)a_{i_1\dots i_p}$. Is that somewhere in your paragraph?

As always, I recommend playing with a few concrete examples to develop intuition and experience.

Comment: I edited. You are right I forgot about this. I added this in my post. But then : in fact is there a simple formula to compute $\alpha(v^1,...,v^p)$ in a general case or it is "complicated" ? Indeed I have all the informations to compute it but in a general case I don't know if I can find a simple formula by doing more simplifications.

Comment: It's not conceptually complicated, but it's computationally intensive. Remember that $dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}(v_1,\dots,v_p)$ will be the determinant of the matrix you get by using only the $i_1\dots i_p$-coordinates of $v_1,\dots,v_p$. So you will get a linear combination of such determinants.

Comment: By the way, you should only use $v^i$ as the *components* of a contravariant tensor (i.e., vector field), not for enumerating different vector fields.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot the formula with the determinant. Thank you

Comment: Yes, everything is built out of determinants. $\Lambda^n(\Bbb R^{n*})$ is $1$-dimensional, with $\det$ giving a basis. (For my undergraduate multivariable math class, I didn't teach tensors at all, but did everything just with determinants. You can find a link to those lectures, if you're interested, in my profile.)